# Android: layout issues, the layout is different in emulator than in preview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am using android studio, but I do not know why it is showing the different layout in emulator. So I want an action bar in my layout but in emulator only blank layout is shown.

layout XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/listToDo"
    android:weightSum="1">

 <ListView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/list">

     </ListView>
```

menu xml:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<item android:id ="@+id/home"
      android:title ="home"
       android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction ="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:title="clear all"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    </menu>
```

In the preview, it shows the layout that i want to have. I am using Nexus 5 as an emulator

Comment: lovely xml `weightSum="1">>`

Comment: @Blundell I remove one of it but it does not solve the problem

Comment: Try a different emulated device and see if it has the same problem.

Comment: @Mike I forgot to mention this. This is the second layout, which is called from a "home layout". The home layout looks perfectly fine: with an action bar and a menu item. But this layout for some reason is not display correct design.

Comment: The Preview cannot know about your styles. So in your styles.xml you should extend sth with an actionbar, i.e. <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> Im not quite sure if you really mean emulator. The preview window in Android Studio can be customized next to the orientation button.

Comment: @wegsehen I just chose the app theme using one of the setting in android studio. I did not extend anything for my home layout. But it still works perfectly fine on emulator.

Comment: And on a real devices? And did you extend the 2nd activity from ActionBarActivity when using Appcompat?